# Importing related modules in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to import two "sub-modules" that are closely related, and I'm not sure how to import them in a way that shows that they are related. My file structure is as follows:

```
main.py
module/
    child_one/
        one.py
    child_two
        two.py
```

Is there a way to import `one.py` and `two.py` into `main.py` in a way that has them both as "submodules" of a parent, while shortening the name of the parent? For example something like this (which doesn't work, I think having `.` in the name is bad...):

```
import module.child_one as m.one
import module.child_two as m.two
```

I think if I didn't want to shorten the name of the parent, I could just import them as `module.child_one` and `module.child_two` without messing with their names.

Thanks!

Comment: The answers give clever workarounds, but FYI: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#import says the `as` name must be an [identifier](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier) (which cannot contain anything but numbers, digits and underscores).

Answer (score 2):

```
class m:
    import module.child_one.one as one
    import module.child_two.two as two


t = m.one.func_one()
tt = m.two.func_two()
```

It works, but... unusial

Answer (score 1):

from your module add `__init__.py` file

from that file import the two submodules

`__init__.py`

```
from child_one import one
from child_two import two

# or

from child_one.one import func_one
from child_two.two import func_two
```

you can use them by doing

```
import module

module.one.func_one()
module.two.func_two()

# or

module.func_one()
module.func_two()
```

Comment: this is the pythonic way

Answer (score 0):

You could import the whole module, give it an alias and then call each child.

```
import module as m

m.child1.foo()
m.child2.foo()
```

According to the accepted answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function) whether you import the whole module or a single function does not make a difference unless you use the child modules in a loop.